# How to show glossaries entries as acronyms in text?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, glossaries-extra

Maybe there is a built-in solution, but I failed to find any in the `glossaries(-extra)` documentation.

I'd like to write:

```
The \gls{un} is an intergovernmental organization.
The \gls{un} was established in 1945.
```

and get

> The United Nations (UN) is an intergovernmental organization. The UN
> was established in 1945.
>
> **Glossary**
>
> United Nations (UN)   An organization.

That what I've come up with:

```
\newglossaryentry{un}{
    name={United Nations}, % long name to display in the glossary section
    text={UN}, % acronym (short name) I'd like to use in text
    first={United Nations (UN)}, % I'd like automatically substitute the acronym here
    description={An organization} % just the description
}
```

Obviously, this solution lacks some things.

1. How do I reuse the `text` field in the `first` field like `first={United Nations (\usefirstfieldhere)}`?
2. How do I show the long and then the short name in the glossaries section?
3. How do I use display the full name with something like `acrfull`?

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\newglossaryentry{un}{
    name={United Nations}, % long name to display in the glossary section
    text={UN}, % acronym (short name) I'd like to use in text
    first={United Nations (UN)}, % I'd like automatically substitute the acronym here
    description={An organization} % just the description
}

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
he \gls{un} is an intergovernmental organization.
The \gls{un} was established in 1945.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, in my question, I was a step from the solution that's fine for me, albeit it requires some boilerplate:

1. If I declare a `\newabbreviation` I don't have to (re)use the `text`: the typesetting of the `first` occurrence will be defined by the `\setabbreviationstyle`.
2. Here comes the boilerplate in the `name`. If I provide only `description` without `name`, I lose the long version in the glossary.
3. I can just use `\acf` as with any acronym or abbreviation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style = list]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle[abbreviation]{long-short}
\makeglossaries

\newabbreviation[%
name={\glsxtrfull{un}},
description={An intergovernmental organization.}
]{un}{UN}{United Nations}

\begin{document}
The \gls{un} is an intergovernmental organization.
The \gls{un} was established in 1945.
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is built-in in `glossaries-extra`, see section 4 *Abbreviations* of the documentation.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  abbreviations,
  shortcuts=abbr,
  ]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries

\newabbreviation{un}{UN}{United Nations}

\begin{document}

The \ab{un} is an intergovernmental organization.
The \ab{un} was established in 1945.

\as{un}

\al{un}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

(`\gls` also works, but I find the shorthands to be clearer.)

---

If you also want the extra description you will have to define your own glossary style. (You may want to do this in any case, though, so this isn't a huge deal.) An example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  abbreviations,
  shortcuts=abbr,
  stylemods=longbooktabs,
  ]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries

\glsaddkey{extradesc}
  {}
  \glsentryextradesc
  \Glsentryextradesc
  \glsextradesc
  \Glsextradesc
  \GLSextradesc

\newglossarystyle{custom-long-booktabs}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long-booktabs}%
  \renewcommand\glossentry[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &%
    \glossentrydesc{##1}%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\glsentryextradesc{##1}\unskip}%
    \ifdim\wd0=0pt\else
      \ \small(\glsentryextradesc{##1})%
    \fi
    \glspostdescription\space ##2\tabularnewline
  }%
}

\newabbreviation[
  extradesc={An organization},
  ]{un}{UN}{United Nations}

\begin{document}

The \ab{un} is an intergovernmental organization.
The \ab{un} was established in 1945.

\printglossary[type=abbreviations, nonumberlist, style=custom-long-booktabs]

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]